# Can two ratfolk share a mount and if so, what size?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, mounted-combat

So the [Ratfolk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ratfolk) have a nice ability called Swarming:

> **Swarming**
>
> Ratfolk are used to living and fighting communally, and are adept at swarming foes for their own gain and their foes' detriment. Up to two ratfolk can share the same square at the same time. If two ratfolk in the same square attack the same foe, they are considered to be flanking that foe as if they were in two opposite squares.

So my question is can both of them ride the same mount by RAW? If so, as far as I am aware, your mount has to be one size larger than you, because that is how much space is available for riding. Since they take up the space of one creature, they should be able to ride a medium sized mount?

Answer (score 1):

In my first completed campaign, which was Indonesia themed, one the the players was a rat folk with leadership. He had heaps of followers and would ride an Indian elephant. We figured out how many rat folk could ride on it by doubling how the number of medium people that could ride it. Anyone riding the elephant had to have riding related feats.

I never had any issues with running the game that way, since half of his followers kept falling off the damn thing, and the other half could barely hold a weapon.

Long story short, 2 rat folk riding a horse at the same time should not be an issue, assuming they both have the appropriate riding feats. The core rule book and all the other books I own at the moment are very vague and unhelpful on the topic, so I can't quote anything.

Someone else already mentioned it, but a custom/exotic saddle will definitely be required.

Answer (score 0):

There are no official rules for multiple riders on a mount. There are some rules for howdahs to carry multiple people, but that is hardly the same thing.

From a discussion on the paizo.com forum, the general consensus seems to be that:

- The mount has to be able to carry them both for encumbrance.
- The people riding the mount should not take up more squares than the mount itself.

From there, you are pretty much on your own as far as the RAW rules are concerned, however, if I was going to implement something like this, I'd suggest:

- You need a custom-made saddle of sorts (or two saddles that fit) to avoid the -5 penalty on ride checks.
- Both characters need to take Stay in Saddle and Soft Fall riding checks.
- One of the two is the actual "rider", the other is the "passenger". The rider has to make all the ride checks to direct the mount.
- The passenger also suffers from the usual mounted combat penalties, such as requiring Mounted Archery.

Using those rules, the ratfolk would be able to ride a medium creature together as long as their encumbrance allows it. Two ratfolk in full equipment may very well be too heavy for ordinary medium mounts to carry, for example.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with "The people riding the mount should not take up more squares than the mount itself." Since the swarming special is that they don't take up more space than one of them would. Everything I see here works for two small creatures riding a mount, not two swarming small creatures riding a mount. Swarming was an important part of the question and has basically been ignored.

Comment: You should link the discussion you reference. Also, "From there, you are pretty much on your own as far as the RAW rules are concerned," implies that everything before it (i.e. including the forum discussion) is RAW, which probably isn't true.

Comment: My apologies, I mistook the ratfolk size to be medium instead of small, and updated the final conclusion to represent that they are small, not medium.

Comment: I read that discussion before I asked the question on here, and I wasn't particularly satisfied with it. Hence why I ended up asking here.